# Cloudflare bug random 302 redirections

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, nginx, cloudflare

I've an issue with Cloudflare, sometimes (randomly) I have 302 redirections on random an non-existing subfolders, I give you some examples :

```
GET /en/home > 302 > /en/home/sWetZ > 302 > /en/home > 302 > /en/home/qUTIs > 302 > /en/home > 200
GET /en/home > 302 > /en/home/zaIue > 302 > /en/home/zaIue/widUT > 302 > /en/home > 200
```

When I disable Cloudflare, everything seems to work well and no sign of strange redirections.
I've noticed that these redirections happen on resources when header "CF-cache-status" is set to MISS.

It's very annoying because "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTIONS" happen really often which totally breaks the website : javascript, styles and images are not loaded...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please open a support ticket & we can take a look. We wouldn't add a redirect unless you set a PageRule instructing us to do so, so this sounds like you may have something configured incorrectly. Forwarding & cache status are too different things & really shouldn't have any play together here.